# Reservation system for 4 different cars

Tags: java

- I'm a total Java beginner and my class only touched if/while/switch and do loop, class and operators. No SQL or objects yet.
- I made a program with 6 options, the first one being the car reservation. The car is attributed randomly (1 to 4), then the user select the time when the reservation will start. The user can go back to the main menu after the reservation and can thus make another reservation.
- I do not think it necessary to worry about the time of the location ( for example, there is no need to be able to have 2 different reservation for the same car at different time during the day), but each car can only be reserved once. Since the car is attributed randomly, if at first, car #4 is attributed, only cars #1-3 will be available for attribution for the second run .
- I obviously won't ask you to do all the coding for this function, but I would gladly appreciate some reading recommendation that would allow me to know how to code such a system inside my code. I can't seem to understand clearly what I'm reading about the subject in the other "reservation" related question threads.

PS: If it can help, here is my full code using a school-made "Clavier.class" which allow the reading of user's keyboard input.

```
public class Facturation {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
while (true) {
   int Choix ;
   int random;
   int HrDebut;

   final String MSG_PRESENTATION = "Programme de facturation a la minute pour"
   + "\n" + "la location de vehicules electriques. ";
   final String MENU = "----" 
   + "\n" + "MENU" 
   + "\n" + "----"
   + "\n" + "1. Louer un vehicule"
   + "\n" + "2. Facturer la remise d'un vehicule"
   + "\n" + "3. Annuler une location"
   + "\n" + "4. Afficher le montant des recettes"
   + "\n"+ "5. Reinitialiser le montant des recettes"
   + "\n" + "6. Quitter le programme"
   + "\n" + "\n"+ "Entrez votre choix";
   final String MSG1 = "LOCATION" ;
   final String MSG_SOLLICITATION1 = "Entrez l'heure du debut de la location";
   final String NOCAR1 = "Il n'y a plus de véhicules disponibles.";
   final String MSG_ERREUR = "Ceci n'est pas une entree valide";
   final String MSG_RTR_MENU = "Appuyez sur <ENTREE> pour revenir au menu principal" ;

   System.out.println (MSG_PRESENTATION);
   System.out.print (MENU + "\n") ;

    while (true) {
        Choix = Clavier.lireInt();
        switch (Choix) { 
           case 1:
            System.out.println(MSG1);
            double randomDouble = Math.random();
           randomDouble = randomDouble * 4 + 1;
           int randomInt = (int) randomDouble;
           System.out.println (MSG_SOLLICITATION1);

           while (true ) { 
           HrDebut= Clavier.lireInt();
           int HrHHDebut= HrDebut/100;
           int HrMMDebut= HrDebut%100;
           if (HrDebut >= 900 && HrDebut < 960 || HrDebut >= 1000 && HrDebut < 1060 ||
               HrDebut >= 1100 && HrDebut < 1160 || HrDebut >= 1200 && HrDebut < 1260 ||
               HrDebut >= 1300 && HrDebut < 1360 || HrDebut >= 1400 && HrDebut < 1460 ||
               HrDebut >= 1500 && HrDebut < 1560 || HrDebut >= 1600 && HrDebut < 1660 ||
               HrDebut >= 1700 && HrDebut < 1760 || HrDebut == 1800) {
           System.out.println("CONFIRMATION:" + "\n" + 
           "-Location du vehicule no:" + randomInt +
           "\n" + "Debut de la location:" + HrHHDebut + "h" + HrMMDebut 
           + "\n" + "\n" + MSG_RTR_MENU) ;
           Clavier.lireFinLigne();
            break;
            } else {
            System.out.println (MSG_ERREUR);
            System.out.println (MSG_SOLLICITATION1);
             } 
            }
       break;

          case 2: 
      System.out.println("test 12");


    }
     break;  

  } 
}
   } 

}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? This site is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific technical issue.  Your Question might be appropriate on the sister site, Code Review Stack Exchange, but not here

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what to ask because I don't know if there even is a method that deal with reservation.

Say that car #4 is already reserved, is there a way to make the program remember it, and when it goes back to the segment where it attribute a car randomly, only car #1, 2 an 3 are now available for random attribution?

Comment: Would it be too advanced to suggest that this is a good time to learn about objects and collections? I’d develop a simple `Vehicule` class that specifies that each car has a number and a reservation status (true or false) and then put four such objects into a list. You may then shuffle the list before handing out a car. This makes sure that the user gets a random car, and at the same time allows you to try the cars in turn until you find one that isn’t already reserved.

Comment: I have to send only 1 class to the teacher, which means I can't import another class into the first class which would countain those object (unless that's not what you where trying to explain).

I put the random requirement aside and just tried to code something which would give the first car in the beginning , then the second, the third and finally the 4th with a for loop. But as soon as the program go back to main menu, when option 1 for location is chosen again, is restart at car 1 instead of car 2 (or further).

Answer (score 0):

> Say that car #4 is already reserved, is there a way to make the program remember it, and when it goes back to the segment where it attribute a car randomly, only car #1, 2 an 3 are now available for random attribution?

Yes, there is a way.  You use an array or collection to record the reservations; e.g.

```
    boolean[] reservations = new boolean[4];

    // Assuming that cars are numbered from 0 to 3 ...

    // To reserve a car:
    reservations[carNumber] = true;

    // To test if a car is reserved:
    if (reservations[carNumber]) {
         System.out.println("Car " + carNumber + " is reserved");
    }
```

You can do similar things for other information you need to record about cars, reservations and so on.   (Collections would be a better way, but if you haven't learned about those yet ...)

> I have to send only 1 class to the teacher, which means I can't import another class into the first class which would contain those object (unless that's not what you where trying to explain.

1. You can declare a class *inside* another class.  For example:

   ```
   public class Homework {
       private static class Car {
           ...
       }
       private static class Reservation {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can put two or more classes in a single source code file, provided that they are all in the same package, and only one of them is declared as `public`.

So this means that your requirement to submit only one file does not prevent you from writing your code in an object-oriented fashion.